# Select row if you are current user or substitute

Tags: sql-server

Categories

| Category | person |
| --- | --- |
| A | Kate |
| B | Tom |

Substitutions

| Person | Substitute |
| --- | --- |
| Kate | Roxy |

I want to get Category, where person is me or my substitute.
I have variable with current user, so when current user is Kate is okey:

Select category
from Categories
where person = ‘Kate’

But if current user is Roxy, I still want to see the same row.
It should also work when current user not exists in Substitutions table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the lack of sample data, I think an `EXISTS` would likely be the safest bet here:

```sql
SELECT C.Category,
       C.person
FROM dbo.Category C
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.Substitution S
              WHERE C.person IN (S.Person, S.Substitute)
                AND @YourVariable IN (S.Person, S.Substitute))
   OR C.person = @YourVariable;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Tom who isn't in the Substitutions table.

Comment: Added an `OR`, @aniki24680 .